# deploying asp.net source code to webserver

Tags: asp.net-3.5

i am just trying to understand the deployment build model with asp.net

i write code locally on my machine in visual studio and when i hit f5, it starts up a local webserver for all my testing.

then, i FTP all of my source code to my webserver and then hit the real URL.

my question is when does this get compiled on the webserver.  is it looking at the bin/ directory of my local file that i just copied over or is it recompiling the solution and projects on the web server.

Comment: Are you talking about a "Web site" project or a "Web application" project?

Comment: how do i know which one i am working with?

Comment: If it is a web site then the project will look like a file path in the solution explorer. If it is a web appliation, it will be the project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just drop source files (.aspx, .asmx, etc.) in the web site's directory and site is set to allow dynamic updating then each page will get compiled the first time it is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you update it, it gets recompiled. In your bin folder, all you have is classes with code.